# How I can remove all NewLine from a variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I can remove all NewLine from a variable in SQL Server?

I use SQL Server 2008 R2.

I need remove all NewLine in a variable in a T-Sql Command.

For example:

```
Declare @A NVarChar(500) 
Set @A = ' 12345
        25487
        154814 '
Print @A
```

And it printed like this:

```
 12345
        25487
        154814
```

But I want to get strings like this:

> 12345            25487           154814

I write this query, but it does not work:

```
Set @A = Replace(@A,CHAR(13),' ')
```

Comment: NewLine is `CHAR(10)CHAR(13)`. Try to remove that

Comment: to see what ascii characters are http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a newline in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951518/replace-a-newline-in-tsql)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You must use this query

```
Declare @A NVarChar(500);

Set @A = N' 12345
        25487
        154814 ';

Set @A = Replace(@A,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),' ');

Print @A;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to look exactly like in your sample output, use [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql):

```
DECLARE @A nvarchar(500) 
SET @A = ' 12345
        25487
        154814 '

SET @A = 
  replace(
    replace(
      replace(
        replace(@A, char(13)+char(10),' '),
      ' ','<>'),
    '><','')
  ,'<>',' ')

PRINT @A
```

It will first replace your newline's then your consecutive spaces with one. Pay attention that it would be wise to url-encode the input string to avoid nasty surprises.

Answer (score 3):

`Replace(@A,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),' ')` didn't remove all the spaces for me.

Instead I used

`replace(replace(@A, char(13),N' '),char(10),N' ')`

This works well!

Answer (score 0):

The hack with `<>` is nice, but may not work if there are `<>` in the text already (like in HTML).

It would be better to use `char(13)` and `char(10)` instead. First, replace `char(13)` with `char(13)+char(10)`, `char(10)` with `char(13)+char(10)`, and `' '` also with `char(13)+char(10)` to resolve not having both.

Then, replace `char(10)+char(13)` with `''` and finally `char(13)+char(10)` with space.