# Getting unwanted data in select statement of NChar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

On running the below query:

`SELECT DISTINCT [RULE], LEN([RULE]) FROM MYTBL WHERE  [RULE] 
LIKE 'Trademarks, logos, slogans, company names, copyrighted material or brands of any third party%'`

I am getting the output as:
[image]

The column datatype is **NCHAR(120)** and the collation used is **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**

The data is inserted with an extra leading space in the end. But using **RTRIM** function also I am not able to trim the extra space. I am not sure which type of leading space(encoded) is inserted here.

Can you please suggest some other alternative except RTRIM to get rid of extra white space at the end as the Column is **NCHAR**.

Below are the things which I have already tried:

1. RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST([RULE] as VARCHAR(200))))
2. RTRIM([RULE])

**Update to Question**
Please download the Database from here [TestDB](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16TPkrEjeYIbosyuCeMn7iqOkmhaLRnc7/view?usp=sharing)

Please use below query for your reference:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [RULE], LEN([RULE]) FROM [TestDB].[BI].[DimRejectionReasonData]
WHERE  [RULE] 
LIKE 'Trademarks, logos, slogans, company names, copyrighted material or brands of any third party%'
```

Comment: I suspect a control character like CR or TAB.  Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958278/sql-server-search-using-like-while-ignoring-blank-spaces/42958939#42958939

Comment: A `(n)char` will always pad the right side of the column/variable out with whitespace. If you want the value to not have whitespace at the end then you'll need to use a `(n)varchar`.

Comment: How about just comparing the first 92 characters?

Comment: @Larnu, I cannot change the column datatype. But I have also tried to cast/convert [Rule] column in NVarchar(120). It is still containing the leading space. I am suspecting it is not just a simple whitespace at the end. How can I get rid of this extra space if it is not just a simple white space?

Comment: `(n)varchar` won't hide leading spaces, only trailing. In fact, it's it's a leading space, then changing to `varchar` won't do anything (sorry, I must have read leading as trailing >_< ). What does `UNICODE(LEFT([Rule],1))` return?

Comment: @Larnu It is returning 84, Please download the database from the link. And use the query given in the last for your reference.

Comment: No chance I'm downloading an unknown file from someone anonymous. And 84 isn't a space. That's your problem.

Comment: Can you give the result of `UNICODE(RIGHT([Rule],1))`, not `LEFT`

Comment: @Kobi it is returning me 32

Comment: 32 is the ASCII code for a space, you can replace it as I suggest in my answer.

Comment: @Kobi It is **NChar** column. So Anyhow the rest of the space will have white spaces only.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a `non-breaking space` nchar(160) inside the string. 
You can convert it to a simple space and then use the usual `trim` function

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE([RULE], NCHAR(160), ' ')))
```

In case of unicode space

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(RULE, NCHAR(0x00A0), ' ')))
```

Comment: This is also not working, The extra white space is still present there.

Comment: @RahulAnand Might be worth actually putting the data in your question then; an image of your data isn't helpful.

Comment: @Larnu Please download the database from the link provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for ( Not sure ) . Make a try with this approach

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE([RULE], CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

Reference links : [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951705/6122941) & [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28628530/6122941)

Note: FYI refer those links for better understanding .

Comment: I have tried this approach as well. I am still not able to replace the leading space with the empty (White Space) over here.

Comment: why dont you post your samlpe data insetad of DB file .?

Answer (score 0):

change the type `nchar` into `varchar` it will return the result without extra space