# Join not behaving as expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM ChangeLog
INNER JOIN Jobs
  ON CONVERT(Varchar(30), RTRIM(Substring(CAST(XagtableKeyValues as Varchar), 12, 30))) = Convert(Varchar(30), jmoJOBID)
WHERE xagTableName = 'JOBS'
    AND Cast(xagChangeDate as date) = Cast(getdate() as Date)
    AND xagTableOldValues like '%jmpreleasedtofloor%'
```

Now I know that my substring is a JobID, and I know that these JobIDs exist in the Jobs table. However, my query returns nothing. Seperate the two queries and I get what I would expect.

What is the problem here?

And here is another thing I discovered, if I change the `Inner Join` to say a `Left Outer Join`. The query still returns nothing. Despite the fact that if I remove the join altogether, It returns rows as expected.

I ran this query,

```
SELECT Top(10)CONVERT(Varchar(20), RTRIM(Substring(CAST(XagtableKeyValues as Varchar), 12, 30)))
FROM M1_LV..ChangeLog
WHERE xagTableName = 'JOBS'
    AND Cast(xagChangeDate as date) = Cast(getdate() as Date)
    AND xagTableOldValues like '%jmpreleasedtofloor%'
```

And that returns this,

```
29882-01-0001
29882-02-0001
29834-01-0001
29834-02-0001
29834-03-0001
29889-01-0001
29889-02-0001
29898-01-0001
29899-01-0001
29846-01-0001
```

I copied straight from SQL Server Management studio and noticed there is a newline character between the entries. So, How do I remove the newline character? `RTRIM` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Although this all still begs the question, why didn't the Left Outer Join Work?

Comment: try removing clauses in the where to check if thats the problem or check what `CONVERT(Varchar(30), RTRIM(Substring(CAST(XagtableKeyValues as Varchar), 12, 30)))` does return since it may be producing an extra character

Comment: Are the JobID's integers?

Comment: Nope, They're VarChar.

Comment: also @myacobucci can you add a couple of rows of your data so we can help you better

Comment: It was a newline issue, found my answer here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951518/replace-a-newline-in-tsql

Comment: You're still filtering on columns after the join. And if you're filtering on columns from the inner table then you're effectively negating the left join anyway.