# SQL data stored in two lines

Tags: sql

I have some data that stored as two lines: Example is the address:

`100 Blvd apt 100` ==> this is how it reads in the database. when I copy and paste the address then it is in two lines:

```
100 Blvd
Apt 100
```

How to update this record to be one line only.

Any help appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a newline in TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951518/replace-a-newline-in-tsql)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SQL Server......

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there's a line break in your string.  So either remove them all, or use a SQL query to strip out line breaks.

e.g

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME_GOES_HERE, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

Or, if you want to replace newlines with a space:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME_GOES_HERE, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ' ')
```

Comment: Last `''` needs to be `' '` else you will munge everything together

Comment: Correct in this instance, yes, although sometimes 'munging everything together' is the desired outcome.  Edited for posterity