# Identifying text strings that are problematic when pasting from SQL Server MS 2012 into Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, paste, ssms-2012

A lot of the front end user's don't give a rat's ass about data input quality. My SSMS query retrieves the data beautifully with the correct number of rows output, as expected. 
[image]

On pasting into Excel you get a different number of rows and the set needs playing around with. I believe it's because the data input in that field is weird / non-standard.

[image]

Is the only way to fix this editing the source data or making a big exception clause? I don't want to go via csv and text to columns either.

Comment: You can't copy from SQL Server, it's a *server*. You can only copy from client applications. Are you talking about SSMS perhaps? Why *copy* when you can *export* to a CSV directly from the results, or use the Export wizard to actually produce Excel files? Or use a query in Excel to load the data instead of copying it?

Comment: As for this specific problem, the text probably contains newlines. Any method *except* copy/paste would put the entire content in a single cell. When copy/pasting though Excel has no idea that this newline should be ignored while that newline means there's a new line. Try "Paste Special > Text" to strip formatting characters while pasting

Comment: The way I work is get the data from management studio, paste into excel. Do some analysis and tell the client. I do this hundreds of times a day. My excel book is just called book1 with loads of sheets. I don't even save it. 

Secondly, using an excel sql query editor or doing it through Connections sql command is not a good solution to my problem

Comment: Actually it is. The way you work is the actual problem. Why use *SSMS* to query? Why repeat the process each time when Excel has an excellent querying and cleanup mechanism with PowerQuery? Create the query *once* and just hit F9. Anyway, this question isn't about programming, it's about pasting into Excel.

Comment: If you don't want to do anything else, use [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  in your query to replace newlines with spaces or remove them altogether, [as shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951518/replace-a-newline-in-tsql)

Comment: It's not one query though. I write a whole load every day. Are you saying that I should do away with management studio to get around this problem?

Comment: Many thanks Panagiotis! That REPLACE will work for me.

Comment: also pal, do you know how I can find out which records have newlines?