# How to put the powershell errors into a single column

Tags: sql-server, powershell, xp-cmdshell

I am running a PowerShell script(which runs a loop) using XP-cmdshell. I am trying insert the error output into a temp table. My script returns single line warning as well as multiple line errors from PowerShell. The errors are inserted into multiple cells rather than single cell. I know PowerShell returns error in multiple line. Is there a way to accommodate the errors in the single cell and also how to remove CrLf(SQL carriage return and line break) while inserting the error from PowerShell to temp table.

`Insert into #ErrorLog`
`Exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell <My Script>`

Comment: If you want to remove the line breaks, does this answer your question?[Replace a newline in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951705/2029983)

Comment: Can we get some context in regards to a code sample? In could be as simple as `-join ";"`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Am using ```Copy-DbaDbTableData``` cmdlet to copy the tables from one server to another.

Comment: Just have you script normalize the newlines like `($errorMessage -replace '\r|\n', ' ').Trim()`